# PayPal IPN getting 405: method not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-ipn, http-status-code-405

So I can call my IPN handling page (an aspx page) happily using Fiddler to POST a fairly accurate version of what the IPN should be sending, and it works fine. However, as soon as I use the IPN test tool or try a 'real' transaction it throws a 405:

```
2012-01-25 18:46:55 193.128.120.227 POST /paypal_notify.aspx - 80 - 173.0.82.126 - 302 0 0
2012-01-25 18:46:55 193.128.120.227 POST /403_error.htm - 80 - 173.0.82.126 - 405 0 1
```

I just can't figure it out. Calling an ASP page from IPN works fine but ASPX and ASHX both throw 405s. And yet POSTing to the page myself isn't a problem.

If anyone's got any ideas what might cause this I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you first do a redirect to an error page. Paypal tries a POST to /403_error.htm and since that should probably be a GET you get the 405. Something is probably wrong in your paypal_notify.aspx in the first place.

403 means forbidden, so do you have any security scheme that throws the 403?

You might want to post the code you use in paypal_notify.aspx so we can figure out what is causing the 302 to the error page for 403.

Comment: Arrgggghhhh! I'm an idiot! I forgot that we have a Session_OnStart method that kicks out 403 for certain UserAgents and IPs - it's been in the code for about 10 years and I've never had to look at it. God knows what it's matching on but I shall fix it now. Thanks Matthias :)

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes one just needs an extra pair of eyes :)